# First order nonlinear differential inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I have a differential inequality as follows:
$$f'(x)\geq cf(x)^a,\quad \forall x\in[0,1]$$
where $0<a<1,\, f(x)\geq 0$

Wolfram Alpha gives the following answer for the equality:
$$f(x)= ((a - 1) (k_1 - c x))^{1/(1 - a)}$$

I'm interested to find the answer to the inequality. But I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce a new function $r(x)\geq 0$ and add $r(x)f(x)$ to the right side of the inequalty to make it an equality.

$$f'(x)=r(x)f(x)+cf(x)^a$$

Now, solve this Bernoulli differential equation by the substitution

$$z(x)=f(x)^{1-a}.$$

After having obtained the final solution try to eliminate $r(x)$ by estimating the solution.

Answer (score 4):

If $f(x)=0$ for some value of $x$, then $f'(x)$ must be positive or zero to maintain the inequality $f(x)\ge 0$.  If we assume a smooth function $f(x)$, $f'(x)\ge0$ would imply that immediately prior to $f(x)=0$ we had $f(x)<0$, and so if $f(x)=0$ we require $f'(x)=0$.  This yields the trivial solution that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Now consider $f(x)>0$.  In this case we may write
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
  \frac{df}{dx}\ge cf^a \Rightarrow \frac{df}{f^a}\ge c\ dx.
\end{equation}
This is true for all values of $f(x)$ and $x$, and so integrating maintains the inequality:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
  \frac{f(x)^{1-a}}{1-a}\ge cx +d,
\end{equation}
where $d$ is some constant.  Since $0<a<1$ we find that $1-a>0$, and so
\begin{equation}\tag{3} f(x)^{1-a}\ge (1-a)(cx+d). \end{equation}
Finally, since exponentiation by a real positive quantity is monotonic we conclude
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
  f(x) \ge \left[(1-a)(cx+d)\right]^{1/(1-a)}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Is it possible to have $f'(x)<0$ ?

Comment: Sure: if $c<0$ then $f'(x)<0$.  Note that we require $xc+d\ge0$ for $f(x)\ge0$, which means that $x\ge -d/c$.  Since you have not specified a domain of interest, I have assumed we are working with all $x$.  Thus, any solution you obtain with the exception of the trivial solution cannot be globally valid.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I made a little error.  If $c>0$ then $x\ge-d/c$ is the domain of applicability, but if $c<0$ then the domain is $x\le-d/c$.

Comment: Sorry, but how are you concluding from $f'(x)=f(x)=0$ at a point, then $f\equiv 0$

Comment: Thank you for your question @operatorerror, as it highlights a small error in my analysis.  My conclusion that $f\equiv0$ comes from the fact that $f(x)\ge0$ and (from the original problem) is monotonic.  If $f(x)=0$ at some point and we assume it is smooth everywhere, then $f(x)$ (a) changes sign at $x$, (b) changes direction at $x$, or (c) is identically equal to 0 everywhere.  Since (a) and (b) are out, that leaves (c).  However, if $f(0)=0$ or $f(1)=0$, then (a) is still an option.  Thus, you may have a non-trivial solution with $f(x)=0$ at boundaries.

Comment: @MichaelM Thanks for your response after all this time. It would be nice to have a full solution to this (I think there is a serious problem with the accepted answer). I assume point b is the case where $f'(x)=0$, if so, in this case how are we excluding $f(x)=(t-x)^2$ for $t\geq x$, 0 else. Not smooth, but should be able to modify. This modification likely violates diff. ineq. though. It seems somewhat delicate, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @operatorerror As I am thinking about this problem again, I am realizing there is a more fundamental issue with my solution.  Imagine I start off with my solution at $x=0$ and more-or-less follow the equality case up to $x=1/3$, then $f(x)$ shoots way higher (smoothly) than the equality case by $x=2/3$, and then $f(x)$ plateaus at this elevated position.  Clearly, my solution is satisfied, but the original problem is not, as the derivative goes to zero while the value of $f(x)$ is not.  I believe Eq. (2) is the source of this error.  Perhaps $d$ should be a function of $x$?